# Asynchronous task that is canceled when screen is touched in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am developing an application which has 5 animations on each page. each animation is launched when you click on them. to assist the user in 5 seconds if not pressed any image, aid is released. this is repeated for each animation, if you click on the animation 1, when the animation ends, it throws back the counter 5 seconds, but in those 5 seconds is pressed in any animation, the counter should be canceled. as I can manage it? until now did with dispatch_after but not how to cancel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your operations to be cancelable, one easy approach is to use an `NSBlockOperation`.

```
let operation = NSBlockOperation()
operation.addExecutionBlock { () -> Void in
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if operation.cancelled {
            return
        } else {
            // perform your animation
        }
    })
}
```

To start your operation:

```
operation.start()
```

If you want to cancel your operation:

```
operation.cancel()
```

If your operation has many stages, you should periodically check `operation.cancelled` - calling `cancel()` does nothing itself beside set that to `true`.

For more complex work, you can chain multiple operations together in a dependency and put them in an `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: When I call operation.cancell() it stops or continue to the If statement? It's posible in my app that I call NSBlockQueue start when The last start call not check if statement. If I have an animation that lasts 3 seconds, before this animation, the operation is runing and, after the animation, the operation starts another time...

Comment: Ok, I test but not works. The problem is this: When start view I START OPERATION with 5 seconds of delay calling operation.start(). When I clic on animation inside this 5 seconds, I call CANCELL OPERATION and, when animation ends, I call another time the start() method. This make that the CANCELL is not true and the operation is executed before the 5 seconds...

Comment: Don't call `start()` on an operation after you've cancelled it. Make a new operation.